# IPv4 address in AAAA DNS record not working

Tags: networking, dns, android, ipv6, ipv4

#### Background (feel free to skip reading)

I have a server running Wireguard, to which multiple Android devices connect using the [Wireguard app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wireguard.android). This server has 2 WAN connections - a faster line that has a public IPv6 address and an IPv4 address behind CG-NAT, and a slower line with a public IPv4 address but no IPv6 connectivity. I use a DDNS service to keep track of the both the public IP addresses.

The Wireguard app has a problem: when a domain endpoint has an IPv4 and IPv6 address, it prefers connecting using the IPv4 address. (This problem has been already been discussed in [multiple](https://www.reddit.com/r/WireGuard/comments/e05ef1/hostname_in_endpoint_wireguard_uses_ipv4_instead/) [places](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/28666) and it doesn't look like it'll be fixed soon.) As a result, all the clients end up connecting using the slower line and it results in a nearly unusable tunnel.

#### My workaround and the problem

In order to find my way around the above problem, I decided to use a domain with just AAAA records (and no A records), in which the following records will be added:

- `2401:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::1234:1` - the public IPv6 address
- `::ffff:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` - the public IPv4 address in [mapped form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Transition_from_IPv4) (using the correct hex notation for the last 2 segments of course)

My assumption was that this would work perfectly with the first address being tried when IPv6 connectivity is available to the clients and the second when they are in an IPv4-only network (with no IPv6 default route present).

However, when I tried to test this using a domain with just the second type of record (IPv4 mapped address), it turned out that it didn't work at all, neither in the Wireguard app, nor anywhere else.

**My observations were as follows:**

**Assumption:** Say the IPv4 address is 192.168.1.1 and it hosts a web server on port 80, and a domain `some-domain.com` has a single AAAA record pointing to `::ffff:c0a8:101`:

- I can access the web page by visiting `http://192.168.1.1/` in my browser
- I can access the web page by visiting `http://[::ffff:192.168.1.1]/` or `http://[::ffff:c0a8:101]/` in my browser
- Using `nslookup some-domain.com` correctly outputs the address `::ffff:192.168.1.1` in the response
- Using `http://some-domain.com` in a browser or using `ping6 some-domain.com` results in a *name not resolved* or *unknown host* error, respectively.

My question is what causes this behaviour: **what is it that causes end applications to discard the IPv4-mapped AAAA record returned by a DNS server**, although they work fine when the mapped address is given directly without a domain?

Answer (score 1):

Applications don't discard the mapped AAAA record – they don't even *query for* AAAA records at all, when they're in an IPv4-only network with no local IPv6 addresses configured.

This is "standard" behavior in system DNS resolvers on most operating systems (they expect IPv4 addresses to be found only in A records, which I think is an entirely reasonable assumption). For example, the Linux getaddrinfo() function is usually passed the AI_ADDRCONFIG flag to suppress address families that aren't configured, and will skip the A or AAAA query accordingly.

(nslookup doesn't use the system resolver; the entire point of this tool is to make direct DNS queries, so its behavior will always be different.)

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of this. But I am unable to access `http://<my-domain>` (containing just an AAAA record with the mapped IPv4 address) also when I am connected to an IPv6-enabled network (and am able to ping IPv6 hosts like `ipv6.google.com`). The error is the same: _name not resolved_.